# ssh remote execution: can't load library

Tags: shell, ssh, command

I am trying to execute a ssh-command from PC-A on PC-B. Both of them are Unix based.

Whenever I type in the command "`ssh root@192.168.1.213 /path/to/x.sh`" I get this
[ssh error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62xiJ.png) with the error message "`can't load library libimp.so`".

Typing in the commands separately does work though. (1. Type in `ssh root@192.168.1.213` [Return] and 2. `/path/to/x.sh`[Return])

Is there something I am missing out?

I tried searching the web but I got no results at all.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this x.sh script require certain environment variables to be set in your .bashrc or similar file?

Comment: @Kenster the script is pointing to something called "audioplay", which should play a .wav file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sh` or `bash` based on your machine.

```
ssh root@192.168.1.213 bash /path/to/x.sh
```

or

```
ssh root@192.168.1.213 sh /path/to/x.sh
```

Comment: Why? What difference does it make?

Comment: Thanks for the input, but i still get the same library-error even though  using sh in between.

Comment: have you specified shebang on your script?